# Fastlane - undefined method configure for fastlane plugin

Tags: ios, ruby, continuous-integration, fastlane

Following the documentation to create a custom plugin for fastlane.
Got an error while trying to use it :

```
Error in lane my_lane: undefined method `configure' for Fastlane::Mailjet:Module
```

It seems fastlane is trying to call a configure method somewhere.
However since there is no mention of it in the documentation i have absolutly no clue of what i should do.

Plugin available here : https://github.com/tirrorex/fastlane-plugin-mailjet

Call the action in my lane with

```
mailjet(
    api_key: "key",
    secret_key: "key",
    sender: {
      :email => "mail@mail.com",
      :name => "Name"
    },
    recipients: options[:recipients],
    subject: "subject",
    textPart: "
    Text.
    ",
    templateLanguage: true,
    templateErrorReporting: "mymail@mail.com",
    templateErrorDeliver: "deliver",
    templateId: id,
    vars: {
      "success":success,
        "build_link": build_link,
    },
    attachments: attachments
  )
```

The issue seems to be that in my plugin/action i use the mailjet gem.
When i try to call my mailjet action in my lane, fastlane instead is calling the mailjet gem which requires the configure method hence the error.
So it is a naming issue.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: can you show us my_lane lane?

Comment: I cannot, the lane is private code. It is also meaningless to do so. If i remove the call to my plugin from my lane everything runs fine. The problem is in the plugin not the lane

Comment: Then show us the plugin and how you call it in your lane.

Comment: What is the complete output you are getting? Any Stacktrace? What is `Fastlane::Mailjet:Module`? `configure` is not a method with any special meaning or usage in the main fastlane codebase (There are some usages of such methods in tests or in context of `match` only).

Comment: I figured out where the issue is coming. My custom plugin/action is called mailjet and is using the mailjet gem. So when i call mailjet from my lane the gem is called instead of my action, and since i did not called configure before (it is required by the gem) i have this error.
I need to find the proper way to call my action from my module or rename it

Comment: For sure is what you say. I guess is not possible to change your plugin/action name, isn't it?

Comment: @rcarba that's actually what i am considering, easiest way to fix this imo, i have no clue how ruby naming works :/

Comment: Fixed it by creating a new plugin with a different name. If you guys know how to solve it differently don't hesitate to share